# java.sql.SQLEXCEPTION: unable to open database file

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-7

I am using sqlite database and need to delete a row from the table and getting error saying sqlexception unable to open database file, I couldn't trace where the problem lies as my coding is very clear as shown below please help!

```
private void delete_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        int b=tableEmployee.getSelectedRow();
        String a=(tableEmployee.getModel().getValueAt(b,0).toString());
        String sql= "DELETE FROM employeeInfo Where employID='"+a+"' ";
       try{
           pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst.execute();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");
       }
       catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }

    }
```

Comment: can you specify proper exception stack trace

Comment: Dear Niks, I am getting the error after running it normally when I try to delete a row from my table after execution of my program and here is what it says  "java.sql.sqlexception: unable to open database file"

Comment: Have you checkout your connection details ? Mean the parameters that set for the connection-string. Maybe there's sth wrong that lead to SQL‌-Exception before running the code.

Answer (score 0):

can u specify what the error is??
or the line in whcih ur gettting error?

Figure it  the folder that contains the database file,further  must be writeable by the user and since it is a web app it will be running as a user that did not have the correct permissions.

besides sqlLite is not well suited for multiuser operation. it locks the database by creating a lock file in the same directory as the database.

If you know it shouldn't be locked you can delete that file to unlock it.

Comment: the error message is as follows: java.sql.sqlexception: unable to open database file,  where can I delete the file to unlock it can you please help thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete lock file 
Go to your Database directory 
You will find a file  yourdbname-journal. delete this file and it should works